# MySQL install issue on Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, mysql

I'm installing MySQL community server edition on my Windows 10 PC.

I'm using the MSI installation for Windows. The configuration doesn't start the server and ends with the following error:

```
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3390 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 0: Reading from the stream has failed.
```

However, I'm not able to skip without a password in the wizard.

I'm not sure what to do next to try to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Trouble Installing MySQL Server on Windows 10

Quick list of items to try to help with this issue and in order perhaps too...

- Uninstall MySQL Server if necessary
- Reboot the PC
- Delete `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`
- Disable Windows firewall

  - > ***From an elevated command prompt run:***
    >
    > To **disable**: `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`
    >
    > To **re-enable**: `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state on`
- Disable anti-virus software
- [Download the MySQL Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html) install file again and then  reinstall with it

---

### Further Resources

- [Download MySQL Installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html)